# readline: unix-word-rubout, but backwards, is it possible?

Tags: bash, readline, inputrc

I'm trying to set up my `.inputrc` to perform a backwards `unix-word-rubout` but I'm currently failing at doing so.
I have `M-w` mapped in my `.inputrc`.

this does not work:

```
"\eu": universal-argument
"\ew":  "\eu-1\C-w"
```

nor does this:

```
"\ew":  "\e-1\C-w"
```

not even doing it interactively in the shell by pressing `M--` followed by `C-w` works, i.e. it keeps deleting words on the left of the cursor.

PS I know there are other kill/rubout readline commands but i really would like to have the `C-w` behavior of killing words using space as separator, just backwards.

Comment: You want to delete the word to the right of point? \ed kill-word

Comment: @bdowning nope, that doesn't quite use the same separator, kill-word is more granular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In brief, add the following lines to `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\ew": kill-region
"\ea": '\e \C-] \ew'
```

where `w` and `a` characters could be changed to your will.

#### How does it work

Let's assign a key sequence to the `kill-region` readline command, for example <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>

```
"\ew": kill-region
```

then let's assign the following macro to another sequence, say <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>:

```
"\ea": '\e \C-] \ew'
```

that performs the following actions:

```
\e<SPACE>:
```

set the mark where the cursor is

```
\C-]<SPACE>:
```

search for a space and move the cursor there

```
\ew:
```

kill the region between mark and cursor

Comment: I think you want character-search-backward, i.e. change `\C-]` to `\e\C-]`.

Comment: @Mikel: no, I understand that with "backward" the OP means "in the reverse direction with respect to \C-w", and given that `\C-w` kill from the cursor to the previous space on the left, I built an analogous function to kill from the cursor to the **next** space on the right.

Comment: yep @enzotib is right. Poor choice of words on my part. I'll try enzotib's solution and let you guys know.

Comment: Ah.  OP wants kill-word, but using space as delimiter. :-)

Comment: yeah, it works but has an issue with EOL, in that since it searches for a space it cannot find the end of line. But I guess there's no way around it, right?

Comment: @GiuseppeRota: no programmatic solution come to mind, only to suggest to the user to use `\C-k` or `\ed` is such a case.

Comment: gotcha, I'll mark it as accepted.